# If $A-I$ is positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is known that if a matrix $A$ is positive definite (i.e., $A>0$) then it will be invertible. What about the following:

If $A-I$ is positive definite then $A$ is invertible. Is this true?

Comment: $A-I$ positive definite  implies $(A-I)+I=A$ is, too.

Comment: Eigenvalues of $A$ are shifted $+1$ with reference to   $A-I$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @kimchilover in the comment, if $A-I>0$ then so $A$, since:
$$A=(A-I)+I>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason why $A-I$ being positive-definite implies that $A$ is positive definite is because the set of positive-definite matrices is a convex set.  Hence whenever $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, then $A+B$ will be as well.  The convexity however doesn't guarantee that subtracting positive definite matrices will yield another positive definite matrix (though it will be symmetric at the very least).